# How can I load an image into tkinter?

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I'm trying to load an image into tkinter, to use as a background image. The image is a GIF (originally JPG, but I heard that tkinter doesn't support that format) with the same dimensions as the window. Anyway, when I ran my code, it ran, but the tkinter window was empty! Here's my code for the window:

```
class Window(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.geometry("700x600")
        self.resizable(False, False)
    
    def background_img(self, img_path):
        background_img = PhotoImage(file=img_path)
        background_img_label = Label(self, image=background_img)
        background_img_label.place(x=0, y=0)

window = Window()
img_path = "background.gif"
window.background_img(img_path)
window.mainloop()
```

Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are using the name `background_img` both for the function name and the image itself, so the definitions override each other. Change one of them.

Comment: Thanks @TDG but I tried that and it's still giving me a blank screen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As [TDG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3426328/tdg) said, the names `background_img` (function) and `background_img` (tkinter.PhotoImage) override each other. You should rename one.

Comment: Ok, I tried that and it's still giving me a blank screen.

Comment: @manologgon Have you tried renaming the background image to `self.background_img`? See [Why don't tkinter images show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16424091/16775594).